# How to install mumbojumbo games on mint?

Tags: linux-mint, games

I heard there are some mumbojumbo games on ubuntu's software center.

How can I install theme on linux mint?

Comment: Which games are you interested in?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use this to install the Ubuntu Software Center and then change your `/etc/lsb-release` file temporarily to `Ubuntu`.

Install the applications that you want from SC and then be sure to revert the `/etc/lsb-release` file back to `LinuxMint`.

*Mint's string*

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
```

*Ubuntu's string*

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
```

Details and the SC installation are available here:

- [software-center - Utility for browsing, installing, and removing software](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/software-center)